# Can I conveniently converty QVariant back to QList<MyType>?

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

It is possible to convert `QList<YourType>` to `QVariant` provided you declare your type as q meta type using this macro:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType);
```

After that, the conversion is even implicit:

```
QList<MyType> list;
QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(list);
```

Now my question is how to convert `variant` back to `QList<MyType>`.

Comment: have you tried variant.value<QList<MyType> >()?

Comment: @Fabio Seems to compile all right, but how can I tell whether some `QVariant` actually contains my list? It doesn't seem to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QVariant` provides method [`canConvert<T>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#canConvert) that you can use to check:

```
 if( variant.canConvert<QList<MyType>>() ) {
     QList<MyType> list = variant.value<QList<MyType>>();
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clearly combine what I got in comments and the accepted answer.

```
QList<MyType> convertToMyType(QVariant variant) {
   if( variant.canConvert<QList<MyType>>() ) {
       return variant.value<QList<MyType>>();
   }
   else {
       // Exception? Empty list?
       // depends on circumstances
   }
}
```