# Trouble of mutating QList which is actually QVariant without copying it

Tags: qt, qvariant

Unfortunately, our software uses certain data-holding object called `ProcessContext` which holds the data in string indexed map (`QMap<QString, QVariant>`. This patter will not be changed right now but I need to stuff more complex data than string and numbers to it.

My specific data is a `QList<MyClass>` which contains instances of my own class. Surprisingly such list really can be converted to and from `QVariant`. I asked question about that: [Can I conveniently converty QVariant back to QList<MyType>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36623931/607407)

The procedure looks like:

```
QList<MyType> list_original;
QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(list_original);
// And later on...
 if( variant.canConvert<QList<MyType>>() ) {
     QList<MyType> list_new = variant.value<QList<MyType>>();
     ...
 }
```

Now the issue here is, that any changes done to `list_new` will not affect the data in the `QVariant variant`.

My question here therefore is how to ensure that the `QVariant` returns refference on the data it covers, rather than copy.

Comment: is it not possible to set the variant variable to the changed list?

Comment: It is but feels dirty. It also means care must be taken to first do all the changes and then update the value in `QVariant`. That's simple in a single function, but not if the `QList` is assigned to a class property...

Comment: You can't that way. QVariant stores a copy and `value()` returns a value, so a copy. Wrap a (smart) pointer instead?